# Databinding HttpWebRequest - StreamReader

Tags: c#, asp.net

Need some advice. I've setup the following HttpWebRequest, which goes over to another server and retrieves data from there in htnl format - but I can change this to another structre.

What I would like to do is databind the data from there and present it nicely using repeaters and a list control in my website.

I've got most of code here below. The question I need to ask is, can I databind my responseData object the way I've got it setup. Secondly, I can configure the page at the other end to produce output in most formats. If I have customername,contact,telephone,email, how shall I present structure wise so I can use it as a databind object?

Hope the question makes sense. Thanks as always

```
    string url = "https://myaddress/customerlist.php";

    // creates the post data for the POST request
    string postData = "ID=" + username + "&Token=" + token;

    // create the POST request
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    webRequest.ContentLength = postData.Length;

    // POST the data
    using (StreamWriter requestWriter2 = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        requestWriter2.Write(postData);
    }

    //  This actually does the request and gets the response back
    HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

    string responseData = string.Empty;

    using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
    {
        // dumps the HTML from the response into a string variable
        responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    ReportRepeater.DataSource = responseData;
    ReportRepeater.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should transform `responseData` in a list of custom object in order to bind it to the repeater

```
IList<Contact> contacts = ParseResponse(responseData);

ReportRepeater.DataSource = contacts;
ReportRepeater.DataBind();
```

Where ParseResponse is a custom method like this:

```
IList<Contact> ParseResponse(string response)
{
   var rtn = new List<Contact>();

   //some loop to create contacts
   //rtn.Add(newContact);

   return rtn;
}
```

A good explanation to how use repeater: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163780.aspx

Comment: Thanks, will read up on the article. Just created my Contact class, but I cant figure out ParseResponse command. I cant figure out which namespace to use or is it custom?

Comment: PasrseResponse is a method you should implements to create the IList

Comment: I'm just working through examples at the moment (although haven't created my loop for parseresponse, but I know the theory thanks to your response)

Comment: @JK36 I know it would seem silly but if my answer solved your problem please mark it as solution

Comment: Ok no problem, just a quickie. if I am passing the following in my response data, how would I construct my foreach loop. I've got 4 rows of data in the follwong format "CustomerID, Customer_Name, Customer_Email". Thanks

Comment: @JK36 you could use String.Split and foreach into resulting array